# Unable to host AspNetCore API in IIS

Tags: .net, iis, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a .NetCore 2.2 API and I'm unable to host it in IIS.
I have followed all the steps in this guides:

1. [Host and deploy ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/?view=aspnetcore-2.2).
2. [Host ASP.NET Core on Windows with IIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/index?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

I'm using OutOfProcess hosting model and Framework Dependent deployment.
I published the app to a folder in C://, created the Site and AppPool, granted the user permissions to the folder, installed the .NetCore hosting bundle, enabled IIS, added the hostname to host file.

When I access the site in the browser it says "Can't access this site". Nothing from IIS AspNetCore Module is shown in EventViewer, no stdout logs are created (logs folder is there), my application logs are not created (log4net) and no logs are created in inetpub/logs/ so I don't have a clue what could be wrong.

Any help is appreciated, don't know what to do with this one as no info to troubleshoot is created. If you need more information just let me know.

Comment: Did you restart the server after installing the hosting bundle?

Comment: Yes I did, already have a couple of days with this issue so I have restarted multiple times

Comment: It sounds like your app is failing to start. Navigate to your app directory in a command prompt and run `dotnet MyApp.dll`. See if there's any exceptions thrown during startup.

Comment: Application starts without issues with dotnet, even tested routes with postman succesfully

Comment: For 2.2 you should stick to in-process hosting.

Comment: You installed `Hosting Bundle`before `iis`, try to reinstall `Hosting Bundle`. Check [Install the .NET Core Hosting Bundle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/index?view=aspnetcore-2.2#install-the-net-core-hosting-bundle)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have valid windows path in your IIS web site e.g. **c:\** not **c:/** etc...