# Bad Request - Invalid hostname on Net 6 Web API deployed in IIS Express

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0

I'm triying to deploy my web API from IIS Express. If I run the project from Visual Studio 2022, it works correctly but if I deploy it from IIS, it shows me a "Bad Request - Invalid hostname" error.

I´ve the next configuration:

- Hosts file: 127.0.0.1 webapi2.com
- IIS applicationHost.config: [ApplicationHost.config bindings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/svm8x.png)
- I already gave permissions to my IIS User to access all inetpub directories: [Permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FqNKf.png)

I'm expectig to deploy the API on IIS Express.

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved it installing again the hosting bundle, after IIS, as I could read in [Unable to host AspNetCore API in IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54023463/unable-to-host-aspnetcore-api-in-iis?rq=2)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).